# Cocos2d v3.0 - Animating Sprites

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I am having a little problem animating sprites in Cocos2d-ios v3.0.

I have tried following suggestions from other posts here with similar questions, but I can't get it to work.  I am trying to animate a sprite with just 2 .png images, but everything I try gives me an  error.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
//adding the png with all the sprites
CCSpriteBatchNode *runSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"run.png"];
[self addChild:runSheet];

//The sprite animation
NSMutableArray *runAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i)
{
    [runAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"run%d-HD.png", i]]];
}
CCAnimation *runAnim = [CCAnimation
                         animationWithSpriteFrames:runAnimFrames delay:0.1f]; //Speed in which the frames will go at

//Adding png to sprite
fufunakan = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"run1-HD.png"];

//Positioning the sprite
fufunakan.position  = ccp(self.contentSize.width/8,self.contentSize.height/5);

//Repeating the sprite animation
CCActionAnimate *animationAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:runAnim];
CCActionRepeatForever *repeatingAnimation = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:animationAction];

//Animation continuously repeating
[fufunakan runAction:repeatingAnimation];

//Adding the Sprite to the Scene
[self addChild:fufunakan];
```

The error message I am getting is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

If anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: add an exception breakpoint and tell us what line the error is on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: LearnCocos2D - The where the error is on is     [runAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"run%d-HD.png", i]]];  in the for statement.

Comment: Ah! you're adding the png to the batchnode, but are you adding the plist to the spriteframecache? Something like [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"run.plist"]

Comment: Great! posting my comment as the answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in the comments above.

You are adding the png to the batchnode, but you aren't adding the plist to the spriteframecache? This is what I think is missing.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"run.plist"]
```